# load row database on variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook

I am new about php and mysql.

I start a project for make a little application, and it's work like this:

1. Load API facebook
2. if the ID of user doesn't exist on database, insert ID and username on a specific table of database.
3. after that, load the row of the user where the ID facebook is equal on the database.

the problem is on the third step!!

This is the code:

```
            if ( $loadspecific == "caricadati" ) {
        $query =array() ==  "SELECT * UIDfacebook FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = $id";
        $result = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string($query)) or die (mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "{$row['UIDfacebook']} <br>" ;
        } 

        }else{
            echo $result;

            }  

    mysql_close($dblink);

    //Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
 ?>
```

thank you so much!!!

Comment: it would help to know in more detail *what the actual problem is* (do you get an error? is the data delivered not what you expect?) to help. "the problem is on the third step!!" is very unspecific

Comment: I love this website because the people help seriously for some problem, and I start to use a PHP and mysql 3 days ago... my problem was to load a variable on my database in the php code... I resolve the problem to use a: $query = "SELECT specificVariable FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = $id"; and I repeats this code for all of the variable... with this, I can load the variable from the specific row... maybe, I will have another problem, because I am a little bit confusing about that... but thanks for the reply!! my goal is to play a game on facebook and savegame on my database, and reload...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$query =array() ==  "SELECT * UIDfacebook FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = $id";
```

to

```
$query = "SELECT UIDfacebook FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = $id";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = $id";
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, if I edit the code like this the code will show only the ID of facebook on the database, I need to load the variable of the row like [id,username,score,level...] of the single user... thank you so much!! :)

Comment: you can use $query = "SELECT * FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = $id"; and then while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){} and inside the loop you can get other values like you did for $row['UIDfacebook']

Comment: if ( $loadspecific == "caricadati" ) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM tabletest WHERE UIDfacebook = $id";
$result = mysql_query(mysql_real_escape_string($query)) or die (mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){}
{
    echo $row['UIDfacebook'];
 
} 

}else{
 echo $result;
  //echo $row['UIDfacebook'];
 
the php doesn't make error but i can't see the row on the echo...  thank you so much!! :)